# Bad health due to com.cloudera.cmon.agent.DnsTest timeout

Tags: hadoop, installation, cloudera

**Problems:**

More and more data nodes become bad health in Cloudera Manager.

**Clue1:**

no any task or job, just an idle data node here,

## top

-bash-4.1$ top
top - 18:27:22 up  4:59,  3 users,  load average: 4.55, 3.52, 3.18

Tasks: 139 total,   1 running, 137 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie

Cpu(s): 14.8%us, 85.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

Mem:   7932720k total,  1243372k used,  6689348k free,    52244k buffers

Swap:  6160376k total,        0k used,  6160376k free,   267228k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

13766 root      20   0 2664m  21m 7048 S 85.4  0.3 190:34.75 java

17688 root      20   0 2664m  19m 7048 S 75.5  0.3   1:05.97 java

12765 root      20   0 2859m  21m 7140 S 36.9  0.3 133:25.46 java

2909 mapred    20   0 1894m 113m  14m S  1.0  1.5   2:55.26 java

1850 root      20   0 1469m  62m 4436 S  0.7  0.8   2:54.53 python

1332 root      20   0 50000 3000 2424 S  0.3  0.0   0:12.04 vmtoolsd

2683 hbase     20   0 1927m 152m  18m S  0.3  2.0   0:36.64 java

**Clue2:**

-bash-4.1$ ps -ef|grep 13766
root     13766  1850 99 16:01 ?        03:12:54 java -classpath /usr/share/cmf/lib/agent-4.6.3.jar com.cloudera.cmon.agent.DnsTest

**Clue3:**

in cloudera-scm-agent.log,

[30/Aug/2013 16:01:58 +0000] 1850 Monitor-HostMonitor throttling_logger ERROR    Timeout with args ['java', '-classpath', '/usr/share/cmf/lib/agent-4.6.3.jar', 'com.cloudera.cmon.agent.DnsTest']
None
[30/Aug/2013 16:01:58 +0000] 1850 Monitor-HostMonitor throttling_logger ERROR    Failed to collect java-based DNS names
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/monitor/host/dns_names.py", line 53, in collect
    result, stdout, stderr = self._subprocess_with_timeout(args, self._poll_timeout)

File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/monitor/host/dns_names.py", line 42, in _subprocess_with_timeout
    return SubprocessTimeout().subprocess_with_timeout(args, timeout)

File "/usr/lib64/cmf/agent/src/cmf/monitor/host/subprocess_timeout.py", line 70, in subprocess_with_timeout

```
raise Exception("timeout with args %s" % args)
```

Exception: timeout with args ['java', '-classpath', '/usr/share/cmf/lib/agent-4.6.3.jar', 'com.cloudera.cmon.agent.DnsTest']

"cloudera-scm-agent.log" line 30357 of 30357 --100%-- col 1

**Backgrouds:**

1. if I restart all nodes, then everythings are OK, but after half and hour or more, bad health is coming one by one.
2. Version: Cloudera Standard 4.6.3 (#192 built by jenkins on 20130812-1221 git: fa61cf8559fbefeb5af7f223fd02164d1a0adfdb)
3. I added all nodes in /etc/hosts
4. the installed CDH is 4.3.1.
5. in fact, these nodes are VMs with fixed IP address.

Any suggestions?

BTW, where can I download source code of com.cloudera.cmon.agent.DnsTest?